# How to draw a circle in Elm version 0.18.0?

Tags: elm

I wanted to create a circle with this example code but it's not working with latest Elm version.

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (..)
import Graphics.Collage exposing (..)
import Color exposing (..)

main = 
  color brown canvas

canvas = 
  collage 200 200 
    [filled blue (circle 10)]
```

Comment: if the answer below answered your question, accept it by clicking the check (tick mark) next to the answer. Always accept answers that solve your problem.

Comment: Hi @TenTen okay sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are referencing an example from a previous version of Elm. An updated version of your code would look like this:

```elm
import Element exposing (..) 
import Collage exposing (..) 
import Color exposing (..)

main = 
    Element.toHtml (color brown canvas)

canvas = 
    collage 200 200 
        [filled blue (circle 10)]
```

This requires the [`evancz/elm-graphics`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-graphics/1.0.1) package.